# Match set of string representations of Python complex numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match a set of complex numbers with re.match(). I am pretty sure the regex should work but still Python doesn't return anything.

```
pattern = '\.\d+\.\d+\w\.'
value = str(complex(17, 80))
string = '' + value
print(re.match(pattern, string).group())
```

The output should be something like:

```
(17+80j)
```

But instead it is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Try to see (debugger or print) what do you have in re.match(pattern, string) i suspect it's None

Comment: [match](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) returns `None` if the string does not match the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern = r'.\d+.\d+\w.'
```

Comment: So eventually I was wrong about the pattern :))) Thanks Alfe!